# Reactjs, Rxjs and mouse events

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, reactjs, rxjs

I'm trying to piece together a draggable component using Rx and React using various articles, examples etc. (First time I've tried using Rxjs). So far, my code is

```
var Draggable = React.createClass({   

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      x: 0, 
      y: 0
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function () { 
    var dragTarget = $(this.getDOMNode())
    this.mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mouseup')
    this.mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    this.mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown')

    this.mousedrag = this.mousedown.flatMap(function(md){          
      var startX = md.offsetX
      var startY = md.offsetY
      return this.mousemove.map(function(mm) {
        mm.preventDefault()
        return {
            x: mm.clientX - startX,
            y: mm.clientY - startY
        }
    }).takeUntil(this.mouseup)
  })

  console.log(dragTarget)
  console.log(this.mouseup)
  console.log(this.mousemove)
  console.log(this.mousedown)
  console.log(this.mousedrag)

  this.subscription = this.mousedrag.subscribe(function(pos){   <= Error here - No Listener Found 
    console.log(pos)
    this.setState({
        x: pos.x,
        y: pos.y
    })
    this.props.onDrag(pos)
  })    
},

  render: function () {
    console.log("render:"+ this.state.x)
    console.log("render:"+ this.state.y)
    // transferPropsTo will merge style & other props passed into our
    // component to also be on the child DIV.
    return this.transferPropsTo(React.DOM.div({      
      style: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: this.state.x + 'px',
        top: this.state.y + 'px'
      }
    }, this.props.children))
  }
})
```

Now I'm not sure if I've even architected this correctly. What I am finding is that Rx is failing with a No Listener Found error on the mousedrag.subscribe line **during the call to subscribe**. The Console.log tells me that mouseup, mousemove and mousedown all have undefined sources - but I'm not sure why since the dragTarget is correctly - apparently - set to the DOM element underlying this component or at least a DOM element (see [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-Examples/blob/master/dragndrop/dragndrop.js) for the example I've drawn from).

Now I'm not sure where the problem resides. I tended to think that the componentDidMount event seemed like a reasonable place to set up all the Rx magic(!). But I'm wondering if I'm too early, I should be binding to this somewhere, making a silly mistake or just not got the thinking straight.

(So I also tried [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattpodwysocki/d8bGW/2/) and it didn't work for me either - but with a different error)

Any suggestions/corrections would be most grateful

S

Comment: The links to rx in your fiddle are wrong - they give a 404.

Comment: @ColinRamsay does http://jsfiddle.net/mattpodwysocki/d8bGW/2/ work for you?

Comment: This one works: http://jsfiddle.net/d8bGW/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not worked with ReactJS so this may not be the complete answer.  But the most obvious problem is that you have a context problem.  Within the local functions you are using for your Rx operations, `this` will not be set to your draggable object and indeed all of your properties will appear to be missing.  You need to capture `this` as a variable in your closure so you can access it.  See the `self` variable below:

If this doesn't fix your problem, then elaborate on your error.  When exactly do you get it?  During the  call to subscribe?  Or only when you issue a mousedown to your element?

(btw you should listem to `mouseup` on `document` instead of `dragTarget` for the same reasons you do it for `mousemove`).

```
componentDidMount: function () { 
    var dragTarget = $(this.getDOMNode());
    var self = this;
    self.mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
    self.mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
    self.mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

    self.mousedrag = self.mousedown
        .flatMap(function(md){          
            var startX = md.offsetX;
            var startY = md.offsetY;
            return self.mousemove
                .map(function(mm) {
                    mm.preventDefault();
                    return {
                        x: mm.clientX - startX,
                        y: mm.clientY - startY
                    };
                })
                .takeUntil(self.mouseup);
        });

    console.log(dragTarget);
    console.log(self.mouseup);
    console.log(self.mousemove);
    console.log(self.mousedown);
    console.log(self.mousedrag);

    self.subscription = self.mousedrag.subscribe(function(pos) {
        console.log(pos)
        self.setState({
            x: pos.x,
            y: pos.y
        });
        self.props.onDrag(pos);
    });
},
```

Comment: thx. I've added a bit of detail re the error into the OP. Using self doesn't seem to make a difference unfortunately and no listener is found again.

Comment: What version of RxJs are you using?  In older versions `fromEvent` did not support jQuery objects.  Newer versions do (as long as [useNativeEvents](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/config/readme.md#rxconfigusenativeevents) remains `false`).  If you are using an older version of RxJs, try calling `fromEvent` on `dragTarget[0]` to pass in the native DOM element.

Comment: 2.3.22 - however requiring rx-jquery (which I hadn't previously) and then using a combo your jsfiddle and your answer has got me sorted. Brilliant. TVM (I haven't got enough rep to upvote your answer!)

Comment: yeah I always use `rx-jquery` and haven't really used `fromEvent` yet.  Glad you got it working.